# Web Page Still Loading - Check What it is Waiting For

Tags: php, networking, request, loading, html

I have a page that never stops loading.  The browser tab icons spins and the status bar says waiting for ....

How do I check what request it is waiting on?  I look at chrome developer tools -> Network but it doesn't show any pending requests.

Comment: You could use a simple software proxy. Generally though, the network tab is all I use.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out **Firebug's net panel** showed the pending request.

Comment: Google Chrome devtools do that too.